# Ito formula for max(X,0) where X is a semimartingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Has anyone ever applied the Ito formula on $|X^+|^2$ for $X^+ = \max(X,0)$ with

$X(t) = X(0) + M(t) + V(t)$, where $M(t)$ is a local martingale and $V(t)$ is bounded variation process. I found it in a lemma for $M$ continuous local martingale but the proof was not provided either.

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: Yes, it's called Tanaka's formula.

Comment: Thanks, yes I found the Tanaka formula so I was able to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Use the fact that $max(x,y)=\frac{x+y+|x-y|}{2}$ and Tanaka's formula.